# How to toggle next ul class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open/close nested sub menus, I have three or four levels of nested `ul`s which are all closed but the first one. When I start clicking on the elements, the next `ul` should open and toggle show/hide. The `js` below it's not fully accomplishing what I am looking for.

**CSS**

```
.closed {
   display: none;
}

.opened {
   display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><button type="button">TOGGLE</button>
     <ul class="closed">
        <li>Two
           <ul class="closed">
              <li>Three
                <ul class="closed">
                   <li>Four</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Trying js:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
   $(this).parent().next("ul").toggle(function()  {
      $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("opened");
    }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("opened").addClass("closed");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$(this).next("ul")` instead of `$(this).parent().next("ul")`, because `ul` is the immediate next element of the button. And you can use `toggleClass` method for toggling class like following.

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).next("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
});
```