# How to add and remove a class to next ul?

Tags: jquery

[Following my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832826/how-to-toggle-next-ul-class/) where the answer was accepted, I am now in a different situation where the html is the following. What I am trying to do is the same, open/close nested uls while clicking on its parent anchor child

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Text</a>
     <ul class="closed">
        <li><a href="">Two</a>
           <ul class="closed">
              <li><a href="">Three</a>
                <ul class="closed">
                   <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.closed {
   display: none;
}

.opened {
   display: block;
}
```

**Not working JS i tried:**

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
});
```

Nothing happens, no errors neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. It was because the priority order of a class is lower than the style attribute. Switching the order of my css worked:

```
.opened {
   display: block;
}

.closed {
   display: none;
}
```